# Attach a mySQL datasource in CF Admin

Tags: mysql, coldfusion

I am trying to attach a mySQL database in CF Admin and I am getting responses like:

Connection verification failed for data source: MySQL56
java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][MySQL JDBC Driver][MySQL]Access denied for user 's/a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLInvalidAuthorizationSpecException: [Macromedia][MySQL JDBC Driver][MySQL]Access denied for user 's/a'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have used every way of listing the data source from localhost to Janice, switched the source and database to MySQL56... See image below.

[image: mySQL and CF Admin pages]

Note that I have many msSQL and Access databases on this server with no issues but this is the first time I have tried to add a mySQL db.

I am at a loss...

Tnx,
andy

Comment: Which version of CF, Andy? If it's an option for you, you'll probably have better luck with the MySQL5 driver, not the DataDirect one. I think the latter is only for the paid-for version of MySQL.

Comment: Does your database have an account named 's/a'?

Comment: My guess is that you either do not have a user named 's/a' or that user does not have permissions to login locally. When you installed MySQL, you should have been asked for the 'root' password. If you are trying to connect using this password, the username would be 'root'.

Comment: Not related to your question, but look at the name of the datasource you are attempting to create.  Then ask yourself what you would name the datasource of another database in that MySql instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi People and thanks for your response.

Turns out I needed to download and install the ODBC driver for MySQL from mysql.com.

There is a very go video on youtube:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3GZidOwGmM

I followed the instructions and everything is perfect.

Scott, I do have an s/a actually "sa" for msSQL username and I thought I had assigned it to MySQL also but "root" was the proper user name.

Andy

Comment: You should not need to use ODBC drivers. JDBC drivers work just fine.

Comment: Also, using "root" to test the db connection is fine. However, it should not be used for the real DSN, for security reasons. Instead, create a separate user and [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) it only the permissions needed.

Comment: Thank you again for your comments. This is for my localhost so security is not an issue. I will upload the dump and / or changes to client server when it is ready. As to the type of connection, I am not a Windows Server expert and the only information I could find via Google search said I needed an ODBC driver and that worked fine.